# Access 2007 select first value of query results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am running into a rather annoying thingy in Access (2007) and I am not sure if this is a feature or if I am asking for the impossible.

Although the actual database structure is more complex, my problem boils down to this:

I have a table with data about Units for specific years. This data comes from different sources and might overlap.

```
Unit | IYR  | X1   | Source | 
-----------------------------
A    | 2009 |  55  |     1  | 
A    | 2010 |  80  |     1  | 
A    | 2010 | 101  |     2  | 
A    | 2010 | 150  |     3  | 
A    | 2011 |  90  |     1  | 
...
```

Now I would like the user to select certain sources, order them by priority and then extract one data value for each year.
For example, if the user selects source 1, 2 and 3 and orders them by (3, 1, 2), then I would like the following result:

```
Unit | IYR  | X1   | Source | 
-----------------------------
A    | 2009 |  55  |     1  | 
A    | 2010 | 150  |     3  | 
A    | 2011 |  90  |     1  |
```

I am able to order the initial table, based on a specific order. I do this with the following query

```
SELECT Unit, IYR, X1, Source
FROM TestTable
WHERE Source In (1,2,3)
ORDER BY Unit, IYR,
IIf(Source=3,1,IIf(Source=1,2,IIf(Source=2,3,4)))
```

This gives me the following intermediate result:

```
Unit | IYR  | X1   | Source | 
-----------------------------
A    | 2009 |  55  |     1  | 
A    | 2010 | 150  |     3  | 
A    | 2010 |  80  |     1  | 
A    | 2010 | 101  |     2  | 
A    | 2011 |  90  |     1  |
```

Next step is to only get the first value of each year. I was thinking to use the following query:

```
SELECT X.Unit, X.IYR, first(X.X1) as FirstX1
FROM (...) AS X
GROUP BY X.Unit, X.IYR
```

Where (…) is the above query.

Now Access goes bananas. Whatever order I give to the intermediate results, the result of this query is.

```
Unit | IYR  | X1   | 
--------------------
A    | 2009 |  55  | 
A    | 2010 |  80  | 
A    | 2011 |  90  |
```

In other words, for year 2010 it shows the value of source 1 instead of 3. It seems that Access does not care about the ordering of the nested query when it applies the FIRST() function and sticks to the original ordering of the data.

**Is this a feature of Access or is there a different way of achieving the desired results?**

Ps: Next step would be to use a self join to add the source column to the results again, but I first need to resolve above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use first it may be better to determine the MIN Priority and then join back e.g.

```
SELECT 
       t.UNIT,
       t.IYR,
       t.X1,
       t.Source ,
       t.PrioritySource 
FROM
       (SELECT 
              Unit, 
              IYR, 
              X1, 
              Source,
              SWITCH (  [Source]=3,     1,
                        [Source]=1,     2,
                        [Source]=2,     3) as PrioritySource 
       FROM 
              TestTable
       WHERE 
              Source In (1,2,3)
       ) as t

       INNER JOIN 

       (SELECT 
              Unit, 
              IYR,
              MIN(SWITCH (    [Source]=3,     1,
                              [Source]=1,     2,
                              [Source]=2,     3)) as PrioritySource 

       FROM 
              TestTable
       WHERE 
              Source In (1,2,3)
       GROUP BY 
              Unit, 
              IYR ) as MinPriortiy

       ON t.Unit = MinPriortiy.Unit and
          t.IYR = MinPriortiy.IYR and
          t.PrioritySource = MinPriortiy.PrioritySource
```

which will produce this result (Note I include Source and priority source for demonstration purposes only)

```
UNIT | IYR  | X1  | Source | PrioritySource
----------------------------------------------
A    | 2009 | 55  | 1      | 2
A    | 2010 | 150 | 3      | 1
A    | 2011 | 90  | 1      | 2
```

Note the first subquery is to handle the fact that Access won't let you join on a Switch

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `FIRST()` does use an arbitrary ordering. From the [Access Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/first-last-functions-HA001231449.aspx?CTT=1):

> These functions return the value of a specified field in the first or
>   last record, respectively, of the result set returned by a query. If
>   the query does not include an ORDER BY clause, the values returned by
>   these functions will be arbitrary because records are usually returned
>   in no particular order.

I don't know whether `FROM (...) AS X` means you are using an `ORDER BY` inline (assuming that is actually possible) or if you are using a `VIEW` ('stored Query object') here but either way I assume the `ORDER BY` is being disregarded (because an `ORDER BY` should only apply to the final result).

The alternative is to use `MIN()` (or possibly `MAX()`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the most concise way I have found to write such queries in Access that require pulling back all columns that correspond to the first row in a group of records that are ordered in a particular way.

First, I added a UniqueID to your table. In this case, it's just an AutoNumber field. You may already have a unique value in your table, in which case you can use that.

This will choose the row with a Source 3 first, then Source 1, then Source 2. If there is a tie, it picks the one with the higher X1 value. If there is a further tie, it is broken by the UniqueID value:

```
SELECT t.* INTO [Chosen Rows]
FROM TestTable AS t
WHERE t.UniqueID=
    (SELECT TOP 1 [UniqueID] FROM [TestTable]
        WHERE t.IYR=IYR ORDER BY Choose([Source],2,3,1), X1 DESC, UniqueID)
```

This yields:

```
Unit    IYR     X1  Source  UniqueID
A       2009    55  1       1
A       2010    150 3       4
A       2011    90  1       5
```

I recommend (1) you create an index on the IYR field -- this will dramatically increase your performance for this type of query, and (2) if you have a lot (>~100K) records, this isn't the best choice. I find it works quite well for tables in the 1-70K range. For larger datasets, I like to use my [GroupIncrement](http://fieldeffect.info/w/VBA_Library#GroupIncrement_Function) function to partition each group (similar to SQL Server's [ROW_NUMBER() OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) statement).

The `Choose()` function is a VBA function and may not be clear here. In your case, it sounds like there is some interactivity required. For that, you could create a second table called "Choices", like so:

```
Rank    Choice
1       3
2       1
3       2
```

Then, you could substitute the following:

```
SELECT t.* INTO [Chosen Rows]
FROM TestTable AS t
WHERE t.UniqueID=(SELECT TOP 1 [UniqueID] FROM
    [TestTable] t2 INNER JOIN [Choices] c
        ON t2.Source=c.Choice 
    WHERE t.IYR=t2.IYR ORDER BY c.[Rank], t2.X1 DESC, t2.UniqueID);
```

Indexing `Source` on `TestTable` and `Choice` on the `Choices` table may be helpful here, too, depending on the number of choices required.

---

**Q:**

> Can you get this to work without the need for surrogate key? For
>   example what if the unique key is the composite of
>   {Unit,IYR,X1,Source}

**A:**

If you have a compound key, you can do it like this-- however I think that if you have a large dataset, it will totally kill the performance of the query. It may help to index all four columns, but I can't say for sure because I don't regularly use this method.

```
SELECT t.* INTO [Chosen Rows]
FROM TestTable AS t
WHERE t.Unit & t.IYR & t.X1 & t.Source =
    (SELECT TOP 1 Unit & IYR & X1 & Source  FROM [TestTable]
        WHERE t.IYR=IYR ORDER BY Choose([Source],2,3,1), X1 DESC, Unit, IYR)
```

In certain cases, you may have to coalesce some of the individual parts of the key as follows (though Access generally will coalesce values automatically):

```
t.Unit & CStr(t.IYR) & CStr(t.X1) & CStr(t.Source)
```

You could also use a query in your FROM statements instead of the actual table. The query itself would build a composite of the four fields used in the key, and then you'd use the new key name in the WHERE clause of the top SELECT statement, and in the SELECT TOP 1 [key] of the subquery.

In general, though, I will either: (a) create a new table with an AutoNumber field, (b) add an AutoNumber field, (c) add an integer and populate it with a unique number using VBA - this is useful when you get a MaxLocks error when trying to add an AutoNumber, or (d) use an already indexed unique key.

Comment: A disclaimer - the SQL police will say "never use an asterisk in your production code!" So get rid of that when you move it into production-- if you want to appease the SQL police. :)

Comment: Can you get this to work without the need for surrogate key? For example what if the unique key is the composite of `{Unit,IYR,X1,Source}`